# django two column foreign key reference to one column

Tags: django, model

```html
class Personal(models.Model):
    Personal_ID = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Personal'

class Tests(models.Model):
    
    Requestor = models.ForeignKey('Personal',models.DO_NOTHING,
    db_column='Personal_ID')
    Analyst = models.ForeignKey('Personal', on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='Personal_ID',related_name='+')
   
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Tests'
```

[I have this problem, I have two columns foreigner key and reference one columns, which works in mysql, but it did not work in Django models. it showed there are two same db_columns in one models and it is not allowed, how to fix it. I will appreciate it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1XoC.png)

[here is the code. how to avoid to use one db_column twice?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXcuV.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1):

db_column =
The name of the database column to use for this field. If this isn’t given, Django will use the field’s name.

Either remove the db_column from both of them, or set them to a different value.

Comment: Thank you. I got that. I find that the reference was automatically assigned to primary key of the parent table. And I db_column is the column of the database table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:
"The name of the database column to use for this field. If this isn’t given, Django will use the field’s name."

Your model has db_column=Personal_ID on two fields. This means that you want to name two fields *Personal_ID*. There should be no duplicate column names; each column must have a unique name.

The solution is to remove db_column=Personal_ID from one of the fields, then the other field can have db_column=Another_Personal_ID

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice help. Yes, I read the docs and find out I used the db_column wrongly. I need use the column name of the database table but not the parent table. Thanks.